# Confused about the different user management options in .Net Core

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, jwt, authorization

I am trying to choose an identity provider for an API that we are creating with .Net 6.

I am looking for something that can use JWT tokens and can also allow for social logins such as google, linkedIn and so on.

I am having trouble finding exactly what I am supposed to do as everything the internet points me to is either depricated or costs a lot of money upfront which we cannot afford atm.

We first decided to try using Azure AD B2C, but that didnt work out because we want to have full control over how login/register/edit profile pages look and we just couldnt do that with Azure AD B2C. And while we could create/edit users through graph API, users would still need to visit Azure pages for login which breaks the whole idea.

I then went through some similar providers like Okta and Auth0, but they have the same problem as the Azure AD B2C.

I then had a look at AspNetCore.Identity, but that, turns out, is deprecated so I guess its not advised to use it anymore.

I think had a look at Duende Identity Server, but that seems to cost quite a lot of money and their free version (according to their website) need to go through an approving process for which we do not have time anymore.

I then found Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, but visiting [this website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio): tells that this also relies on Duende Identity Server and so we are back at point 3, but at the same time it says that this package is under MIT license which should be free, so I am very confused about this one.

Other than this, everything I can find on the microsoft documentation is pointing towards Razor and MVC using their "individual accounts" option which in my case is not helpful because we want to have an SPA app that will talk with the API (with potentially other front-ends as well).

Please help with choosing an identity server or some library that can help us manage users.

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a try to Firebase, It is a Google-owned platform that offers a free tier for user management. Firebase also supports social login and JWT tokens. You could also check IdentityServer4, It is another .NET library that provides a full-featured identity server. IdentityServer4 is open-source and free to use. I have also heard about OpenIddict, It's open source but never used.

Comment: Isn't Identity Server 4 out of support now? According to the website, the developers have moved on to a new product- Duende Identity Server.

I will have a look at Firebase.

Havent heared of open OpenIddict, Ill have to look at it

Comment: I was not aware of IS4. I had used it long back. Yes, I also saw it looks like its also deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple you could look into!

Firebase Authentication: Firebase Authentication is a cloud-based identity provider by Google. It supports JWT tokens and provides social login options for Google, Facebook, Twitter, and more. Firebase offers SDKs for various platforms, including .NET, which can be used to integrate authentication into your API. Firebase provides customization options for UI elements, such as login screens, and you can also use the Firebase Admin SDK to manage users programmatically.

AWS Cognito: Amazon Cognito is another cloud-based identity provider that supports JWT tokens and social logins. It integrates well with AWS services and provides SDKs for various platforms, including .NET. With Cognito, you can have control over the look and feel of the authentication flow using customizable UI components. It also offers user management capabilities and features like email verification and password reset.